# Error while passing values from array to textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the list array values based on comma separated delimiter. Then put this into array with 5 comma separated values. Then I am again separating each array on comma separated values and assigning them to   textbox. 
But I am getting the below error.  Any help please.

> error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
<body>
   <script>
      function functionOne()  {
         var list = "[768.234.232, 768.234.232, 574, 2013-06-29, 2013-06-29, 768.234.232, 768.234.232, 987, 2013-06-29, 2013-06-29]";
         list = list.slice(1,-1);                 // remove the enclosing []
         var allValues = list.split(/\s*,\s*/);   // split on comma with optional whitespace
         var a = [];
         var counter=0;
         for ( var i = 0 ; i < allValues.length ; i += 5 ) {
             a.push( allValues.slice( i, i+5 ) );

             for (var k = 0 ; k < a.length ; k++ ) {
                foo = a[i].split(",");
                for (var j = 0 ; j < foo.length ; j++ ) {
                   document.getElementById('name' + counter).value = foo[j];
                   counter++;
                }
             }
          }
      }

    </script>

    <form>
        <table class="cmn-table" id="t1" border="1"
            style="margin-left: 0.2em; margin-right: 0em">
        <tr>
            <th>Sl.No</th>
            <th>Source IP Address</th>
            <th>Destination IP Address</th>
            <th>Service and Port (TCP, UDP, etc.)</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Expiration Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name11" id="s1" value="1" size="2"
                    readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name0" id="name0" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" size="15"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="name4" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="s2" size="2" value="2"
                    readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name0" id="name5" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="name6" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="name7" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="name8" size="15"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="name9" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="functionOne()">

</body>
```

Comment: Your browser's developer tools probably come with a debugger for JavaScript. Stepping through your code can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo/mistakes in your code: change from (foo = a[i].split(",");) to foo = a[k];
I've made you a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qtsqp/

```
  for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i+=5) {
      a.push( allValues.slice(i, i+5) );

      for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {

            foo = a[k];
            for (var j = 0; j < foo.length; j++) {
                document.getElementById('name' + counter).value = foo[j];
                counter++;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: It has repeated the first rows twice in textbox and not printed the second row in textboxes. This is the same in fiddle

Comment: got it.. just put the second loop out of first loop.

Comment: I was trying to solve your syntax error, not the logical error. Grad that you've found it out.

Answer (score 3):

One issue is here:

```
      for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            foo = a[i].split(",");
```

Did you mean

```
      for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            foo = a[k].split(",");
                    ^ THIS
```

?

Comment: You have better eyes than I do (at least at 10pm)

Comment: Yes, I replaced i with K and issue still persists.

Comment: @Nash: Try using a debugger.